# Introductory condensed matter physics book

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, superconductivity, bose-einstein-condensate, superfluidity

I need a book for general condensed matter physics, preferably at an undergraduate level, e.g. at Ashcroft and Mermin's level or below. Modern applications are preferred.